# perl script to generate random emails

Tags: perl, email, random

I need a script written in perl that will generate 100 random email containing a few digits before @ and static server name after.

Example output:

```
9374567@someserver.net
94853@someserver.net
83754@someserver.net
4001@someserver.net
0962833@someserver.net
etc.
```

Comment: Do you want to generate e-mails, or e-mail addresses?

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
my $i=0;
print int(rand(1000000))."\@email.com\n" while (($i+=1)<101);
```

You can play with the code here: http://ideone.com/D0QN5

Or just with a oneliner (thanks to Phil H for the idee):

```
print int(rand(1000000))."\@email.com\n" for (1..100);
```

Comment: Since he's new to Perl, please add some basics like `use strict`.

Comment: Any reason for `($i+=1)` rather than just `++$i`?

Comment: In fact, just the one liner will do: `print int(rand(1000000))."\@email.com\n" for (1 .. 100);`

Comment: `printf "%d\@email.com\n", rand(1000000) for 1..100`